# Compute $\int_{-1}^{1} T_n(x) T_m(x) \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Define a sequence of polynomials $(T_n)_n$ by $T_0(x)=1$, $T_1(x)=x$, and the following recurrence relation: $$T_n(x) = 2xT_{n-1}(x) - T_{n-2}(x).$$

I have already shown that if $x = \cos(t)$, then $T_n(x) = \cos(nt)$. I need to compute $$\int_{-1}^{1} T_n(x) T_m(x) \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

So far I have used the fact that  $T_n(x) = \cos(nt)$ and the identity $2 \cos(a)\cos(b) = \cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)$ to write the integral as $$\frac{1}{2} \left[ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos(t(m+n))}{\sin(t)} \, dt + \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos(t(n-m))}{\sin(t)} \, dt \right].$$ But I'm not sure how to compute these integrals, or if my strategy is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you forgot $d\cos t=-\sin tdt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=\cos t$ and then $T_n(x)=\cos(nt)$. So
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{-1}^{1} T_n(x) T_m(x) \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
&=&\int_{\pi}^0\frac{\cos(nt)\cos(mt)}{\sin t}d\cos t\\
&=&\int_0^{\pi}\cos(nt)\cos(mt)dt.
\end{eqnarray}
Thus, if $m\neq n$, then the value is $0$ and otherwise the value is $\frac\pi2$.